# Please explain "There are some things it is better..."

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

1. There are some things **it is** better for a father not to know.
2. There are some things **it is** better never to know.

I can't understand how the sentences are grammatical. Isn't **"that are"** better suited than **"it is"**?

Note:
First sentence is from a TV show. Second sentence is from Google Books.

Comment: Does "It is better for a father not to know [this]." make sense to you? We can reverse the sentence "{This] is something [which] it is better for a father not to know."

Comment: @KateBunting Ah, yes, that does make sense.